# Bokeh hover tooltips: How do I not see values that are zero on a graph?

Tags: python, hover, tooltip, bokeh, pie-chart

[Pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxmyx.png)

As seen in the pie chart image above, tooltips is showing P1 along with P2, even if P1  value is 0. Same is the case when I hover over P3. How can I make sure a value is not shown by hover tooltips if the value is 0? In this case P1 value should not be seen on hover but only P2 and P3.

Here is the definition I am calling:

```
def create_priority_graph(P1, P2, P3):

    x = {
        'P1': P1,
        'P2': P2,
        'P3': P3
    }
    colors = ["#e84d60", "#f2c707", "#718dbf"]
    data = pd.Series(x).reset_index(name='value').rename(columns={'index':'toolscore'})
    data['angle'] = data['value']/data['value'].sum() * 2*pi
    data['color'] = colors
    p = figure(plot_height=250, plot_width=300, title="Open Issues by priority", toolbar_location=None,tools="hover", tooltips="@toolscore: @value", x_range=(-0.5, 1.0))
    p.wedge(x=0, y=1, radius=0.35,start_angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), end_angle=cumsum('angle'),line_color="white", fill_color='color', legend='toolscore', source=data)
    p.axis.axis_label=None
    p.axis.visible=False
    p.grid.grid_line_color = None

    return p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix your problem. This code drops 0-value slices as Paul suggested.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models.glyphs import Wedge
import math
from bokeh.transform import cumsum

def create_priority_graph(P1, P2, P3):
    x = {
        'P1': P1,
        'P2': P2,
        'P3': P3
    }
    colors = ["#e84d60", "#f2c707", "#718dbf"]
    data = pd.Series(x).reset_index(name='value').rename(columns={'index':'toolscore'})
    data['angle'] = data['value']/data['value'].sum() * 2*math.pi
    data['color'] = colors
    data = data[data.value != 0]
    p = figure(plot_height=250, plot_width=300, title="Open Issues by priority", toolbar_location=None,tools="hover", tooltips="@toolscore: @value", x_range=(-0.5, 1.0))
    p.wedge(x=0, y=1, radius=0.35,start_angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), end_angle=cumsum('angle'),line_color="white", fill_color='color', legend='toolscore', source=data)
    p.axis.axis_label=None
    p.axis.visible=False
    p.grid.grid_line_color = None
    return p

p = create_priority_graph(3, 9, 0)

show(p)
```

Another workaround where it does not remove the legend for the item that's 0:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models.glyphs import Wedge
import math
from bokeh.transform import cumsum

def create_priority_graph(P1, P2, P3):
    x = {
        'P1': P1,
        'P2': P2,
        'P3': P3
    }
    for i in x.keys():
        if x[i] == 0:
            x[i] = 0.0001
    colors = ["#e84d60", "#f2c707", "#718dbf"]
    data = pd.Series(x).reset_index(name='value').rename(columns={'index':'toolscore'})
    data['angle'] = data['value']/data['value'].sum() * 2*math.pi
    data['color'] = colors
    p = figure(plot_height=250, plot_width=300, title="Open Issues by priority", toolbar_location=None,tools="hover", tooltips="@toolscore: @value", x_range=(-0.5, 1.0))
    p.wedge(x=0, y=1, radius=0.35,start_angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), end_angle=cumsum('angle'),line_color="white", fill_color='color', legend='toolscore', source=data)
    p.axis.axis_label=None
    p.axis.visible=False
    p.grid.grid_line_color = None
    return p

p = create_priority_graph(3, 9, 0)

show(p)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly as I need it, I did not have to use math.pi though, just pi worked for me

Comment: FYI, this fix removes the 0-valued variable from the legend as well. Any way to hack that?

Comment: Added another workaround to my answer where it does not remove the variable from the legend.

Comment: Thank you Jasper!

Answer (score 0):

Since you provided no code, the easiest way to do this would probably be to drop 0-value slices from whichever data you are building your `ColumnDataSource` from, prior to plotting.

Comment: Thank you, but I am not using ColumnDataSource here, attaching code to original post